# Grep $value `grep $value2 `<command>`` - Nested grep?

Tags: bash, grep, nested

I'm a complete noob at awk/sed so forgive me if I'm missing something obvious here.

Basically I'm trying to do a nested grep, i.e. something akin to:

```
grep $value `exim -Mvh $(`exim -bpru | grep $eximID | more`)`
```

Breakdown:

```
grep $value IN COMMAND 
--> exim -Mvh (print exim mail headers) FROM RESULTS OF 
    ---> exim -bpru | grep $eximID | more
```

- `$value` is the string I'm looking for
- `$eximID` is the string I'm looking for within exim -bpru (list all exim thingies)

No idea if what I'm trying to accomplish would be easier with awk/sed hence the question really.

I *tried* to make that as legible as possible but nested nesting is hard yo

***Edit***
Tada! My script is now workings thanks to you guys! Here it is, unfinished, but working:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

    echo "Enter the email address you want to search for + compare sender info via exim IDs."
    read searchTarget
    echo "Enter the target domain the email is coming from."
    read searchDomain

    #domanList is array for list of exim IDs needed
    domainList=($(exim -bpru | grep "$searchDomain" | awk '{ print $3 }'))


    for i in "${domainList[@]}"
            do
                    echo "$(exim -Mvh  $i | grep $searchTarget)"
                    #echo "$(grep $searchTarget $(exim -Mvh $i))"
            done
```

Comment: It is hard to interpret what you are asking -- some examples would be nice. For instance, show us some example data and what the desired output is.

Comment: It maybe possible to do what you want with a pipe.  As is: `grep foo * | grep -v "something_to_ignore" | grep -i potatoe`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
grep $value `exim -Mvh $(`exim -bpru | grep $eximID | more`)`
```

This isn't right. The backticks (`` `command` ``) and `$(command)` do the same thing, it's just an alternative syntax. The advantage of using `$()` is that it's better nestable, so it's a good habit to always use that.

So, let's fix this, we now end up with:

```
grep "$value" "$(exim -Mvh "$(exim -bpru | grep "$eximID")")" | more
```

I relocated the `more` command, for what I think will be obvious reasons. `more` just paginates data for the user, feeding the output of `more` to something else almost never makes sense.

I've also quoted the variables, this is also a good habit, because otherwise things will break when there are certain characters in your variable (most common is the a space).

I can't test if this gives you the output you want, if it doesn't, then update your answer with a few lines of example data, and the expected output.

Comment: i think it needs a closing round bracket ) as they are not matching

Comment: Great answer! One last problem.... why is the script I'm trying to right giving me:
"grep: Only: No such file or directory
grep: one: No such file or directory
grep: message: No such file or directory
grep: can: No such file or directory
grep: be: No such file or directory
grep: listed: No such file or directory
grep: at: No such file or directory
grep: once: No such file or directory"

http://pastebin.com/82bqzEw5

edit - I had that 'eurika' feeling for all of about 30 seconds until this )';

Comment: @nom Your command effectively looks like: `grep "$value" filename`, where `filename` is the entire `$()` command substitution, which is not what you want, judging from your script. I'm not quite sure what your `exim` commands output, but you may want to add the grep to the end like so: `exim -Mvh $(exim -bpru | grep "$searchDomain") | grep "$searchTarget"` ...

Comment: Scratch that, it's a problem with how exim wants to display the headers of a subject via ID. Now to create a for loop to display them 'individually' -.-   edit -- interestingly enough, adding grep at the end doesn't give anything back, not even the error: exim -Mvh $(exim -bpru | grep "$searchDomain" | awk '{ print $3 }') | grep "$searchTarget"

Comment: There are no quotes. That's how it should be: ``"$( "$(... "$var")" )"``

Comment: @Aleks-DanielJakimenko You're right. I forgot that. Thank you for correcting.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to do it with back-quotes (not recommended; it is hard work), then you have to write:

```
grep $value `exim -Mvh $(\`exim -bpru | grep $eximID\`)`
```

(where I've removed the `more` since when used like that it behaves like `cat` and there's no point in using `cat` at the end of the commands like that either).

It would be more sane to use the `$(…)` notation throughout:

```
grep $value $(exim -Mvh $( $(exim -bpru | grep $eximID)))
```

And it seems more plausible that you don't need quite that many sets of indirection and this is what you're really after:

```
grep $value $(exim -Mvh $(exim -bpru | grep $eximID))
```

You should look at:

- [Why didn't back quotes in a shell script help me `cd` to a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12033046/why-didnt-back-quotes-in-a-shell-script-help-me-cd-to-a-directory/)
- [What is the benefit of using `$(…)` instead of back ticks in shell scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9449778/what-is-the-benefit-of-using-instead-of-backticks-in-shell-scripts)
- [Why does `\$` reduce to `$` inside backquotes [though not inside `$(…)`]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7374660/why-does-reduce-to-inside-backquotes-though-not-inside/)

and no doubt there are other related questions too.